# When selected not showing text but selected value change

Tags: c#, winforms

When i compile and run no error (the combo box showing drop down three option) but when i click and selected another text from this combo box the combo box not showing the text that i selected

`dsls` have data eg:

> Id= 0, Name=Text 1
>   Id= 1, Name=Text 2
>   Id= 2, Name=Text 3

```
cmb_ls.DataSource = new BindingSource(dsls, null);
cmb_ls.ValueMember = "ID";
cmb_ls.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmb_ls.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

This application on c# windows form with basic control combo box

Comment: i have 1 combo box and items get from database. When i run application this run normal but when i selected one value from combo box the text not showing correctly

Comment: is it `Name` or is it `Text`, then?

Comment: Wrong type Name not Text srry

Comment: What does "not showing correctly" mean? what does it show?

Comment: When i selected the Text 2, the combo box not showing this text (combo box show blank)

Comment: @BloodTear Where do you call that code you are showing? It almost sounds like you are calling that code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event which would be very wrong.

Comment: Code put in form_load

Comment: @BloodTear Why are you using that overload of `BindingSource` constructor? What if you just use `new BindingSource(dsls);`?

Comment: My first code Load Data from database into DataTbale and set cmb_ls.DataSource = dsls; i search on google and change to cmb_ls.DataSource = new BindingSource(dsls, null); no meaning

Comment: have you written any code for selectedindexchange ? if yes can you post that too..because i do not find anything wrong in the code that u posted.

Comment: I check in SQL field name with type nchar(100)
value wass fill full with blank